# Dependency Injection and Querying GetServices with Generic Interfaces .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm getting myself tied in knots with generics and after some advice. Say I have the following interface:

```
public interface IThing<T>
{
  string DoStuff(T input);
}
```

and the following implementations:

```
public class GenericThing<T> : IThing<T> where T : Person
{
    public string DoStuff(T input)
    {
        return typeof(T).Name;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class GenericThing2<T> : IThing<T> where T : Animal
{
    public string DoStuff(T input)
    {
        return typeof(T).Name;
    }
}
```

Registered as follows:

```
services.AddSingleton(typeof(IThing<>), typeof(GenericThing<>));
services.AddSingleton(typeof(IThing<>), typeof(GenericThing2<>));
```

Is there a way of identifying all objects that implement IThing<> in the services collection?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Do you need to get all registered `IThing<>` instances in controller?

Answer (score -1):

You could iterate over the Service Descriptors in the ServiceCollection and examine the types to see which ones are generic and what the generic type parameters are.

Generally I would recommend registering concrete types in the service provider rather than abstract ones, because it will be difficult to create a service that does not have a concrete type! For example,

```
services.AddSingleton( typeof(IThing<Person>), GenericThing<Person>)
```

You also may want to provide a name string for the service in cases where you want to register the same interface twice, because otherwise there is no way to distinguish between the multiple services when you try to Get Service.  Usually however one tries to avoid registering the same interface twice.

sjb

Comment: I guess my goal is ultimately to pass a collection of IThing to the controller. Maybe I'm constructing this in the wrong way but if you imagine the controller wants to call multiple services of type IThing. I was trying to get around adding many IThings to the constructor.

Comment: Yeah. You need to either (a) specify different variations on the IThing interface (such as for example a series of derived interfaces) and get those variations from the service provider; or (b) specify different names when you register the different GenericThing<Person> variations; or perhaps (c) register an IList<IThing<Person>> instead of registering multiple IThing<Person>'s